# If the service returns JSON data, should I still use this.collection. toJSON()?

Tags: backbone.js, collections, underscore.js, fetch

In my backbone application the REsT service always returns JSON data, so should I always use `this.collection.toJSON()` or can I use `this.collection` directly after collection fetch to bind the data to the underscore template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better to pass Backbone's collection/model objects directly to underscore template, because its handy to add methods to models that output formatted values of the attributes. Check this example (assuming model has custom method `getFormattedDate`)

```
this.$el.html(this.template({collection: this.collection}))

<ul>
<% collection.each(function (model) { %>
    <li><%= model.getFormattedDate() %> — <%= model.escape('title') %></li>
<% }); %>
</ul>
```

But if you decide to pass JSON data directly, then you can't output formatted date:

```
this.$el.html(this.template({collection: this.collection.toJSON()}))

<ul>
<% _.each(collection, function (model) { %>
    <li><%= model.date %> — <%- model.title %></li>
<% }); %>
</ul>
```

UPD: I was wrong about escaping values in underscore templates, because you can use `<%- content %>` syntax to output escaped content. So the only benefit of passing models and collections directly to underscore template is ability to use custom getters of formatted data.

Comment: Better to use getter setter. Like model.get('title'). It's best practice.

Comment: `<%- model.get('title') %>` - also prints escaped titile

Comment: @VitaliyPetrychuk cool, didn't know that. But still I think it's better to pass collections and models directly to template.